# java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, out-of-memory

I am using Apache-tomcat-7.0.12 to run my application,I am getting following error every time i restart the server.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.DedicatedThreadExecutor.execute(DedicatedThreadExecutor.java:62)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5198)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3832)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:424)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1205)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1391)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1401)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1401)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1380)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.DedicatedThreadExecutor.execute(DedicatedThreadExecutor.java:56)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

I have  set the variable CATALINA_OPTS and JAVA_OPTS .
CATALINA_OPTS :-Xms512M -Xmx1024M
JAVA_OPTS :-Xms1024m -Xmx10246m -XX:NewSize=512m -XX:MaxNewSize=356m -XX:PermSize=1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m

but still getting the same error. I am using sts as IDE.

please help me,how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Java applications are allowed to use only limited amount of memory. The exact amount of memory your particular application can use is specified during the application startup. You are doing exactly this by specifying the -Xmx and -XX:MaxPermSize parameters.

the “java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space” message indicates that the Permanent Size area in memory is exhausted, so you can try to increase the parameters already specified.

But looking at your current configuration, you have already set your permgen size to 1024m, so  I can guess that either

a) your configuration changes are not being picked up - for example look into the running processes with ps like following where I see 512m being used as the maximum allowed permgen size:

```
Ivos-MacBook-Pro:testcases ivomagi$ ps axu|grep java
ivomagi           999 195.3  1.5  9644872 129756 s000  S+    4:15PM   0:04.47 /usr/bin/java -XX:MaxPermSize=512m eu.plumbr.demo.GarbageProducer
```

b) you are trying to load something Truly Big (TM), in case of which you need to increase the permgen further